# How to add a class to a div properly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Highlights</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title" class="highlighted">I'm highlighted!</div>
    <div id="text">Highlight me, too!</div>
</body>
```

CSS Code:

```
#text {
background-color: #0B486B;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Vivaldi, Cursive;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 200px;
height: 25px;
}

.highlighted {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

jQuery Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#text').click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('.highlighted');
        });
    });
```

I just don't get it working.
I want to change the style of `<div>` with the id text to the class highlighted
What did  I do wrong?

Comment: It is not polite to just dump a chunk of code for someone else to review. Please use a minimal test case that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to prefix class with `.`, Just use class name

```
$(this).addClass('highlighted');
```

Comment: Thanks for fast response :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#text').click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('highlighted');
      });
  });
```

Don't use the Dot.

Comment: Thanks for fast response!

Answer (score 0):

You can have fun and toggle it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#text').click(function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
        });
    });
```

to avoid having the classe added N-click time